# ClassNotFoundException: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver in Eclipse

Tags: mysql, eclipse, driver

Use Class.forName ("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"); syntax in defining the driver of MySQL in Eclipse as well as in Netbeans. In Netbeans it's perfectly working while on Eclipse it's not working. Already stored the jar file in WEB-INF/lib and already added in Eclipse library.

[image]

Comment: are you able to access the Driver class from inside of a .java file in your project? try testing that out as a first step to debugging.

Comment: Do you have the `driver` in the `classpath`?

Comment: @murtuza we are accessing the driver inside the JSP not in java class. Code is successfully working on Netbeans but not on Eclipse. Unfortunately we cannot use Netbeans

Comment: @AbdullahWasi yes we have the driver.